# Why name Bob after Robert Mapplethorpe in Bottle Rocket?

Tags: character, bottle-rocket

In [Bottle Rocket](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115734/), Robert Musgrave's character is [named Bob Mapplethorpe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115734/trivia?item=tr0664417) after the *infamous* photographer, [Robert Mapplethorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Mapplethorpe). Why did Wes Anderson or Owen Wilson choose this particular name? Were either of them fans of Mapplethorpe's work? Or are they trying to convey something else especially in terms of the relationship between Bob and his brother, John (Future Man)?

Comment: I don't think we can read much more into it other than Anderson (being an exhibited photographer himself) is a fan of Mapplethorpe's work. He has been know to name his characters after artists and friends (Tennenbaum springs to mind).

Comment: @Nobby Well, isn't that already something useful to read into it and worth an answer?

Comment: Didn't think my comment was answer-worthy. Perhaps someone else will dig up more concrete info.

Comment: @Nobby Yes, I noticed that Dignan was also a friend's name. Yet, the use of Mapplethorpe seemed very intentional and something more than a hat tip. Hence my question. It definitely coloured my view of the character. I suppose that it's a bit like calling somebody Osama Bin Laden. (I did not know that Anderson is an accomplished photographer. That does partly answer my question.)

Comment: Is it worth upgrading to an answer then? I thought my response might help shed some light on it, but seems a bit tenuous. And yes, having been to a couple of Mapplethorpe exhibitions myself, I can see how the choice of name could be a tad unusual :)

Comment: @Nobby Perhaps if you can substantiate Anderson's career as a photographer with some links, it might be worth an answer. Something (maybe along the lines of a quote) that links him directly to Mapplethorpe would be a bonus. I see that Sofia Coppola has curated an exhibition on Mapplethorpe and Wes Anderson is good friends with the Coppolas (and the Schwartzmans). Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry coleopterist -  I think I blew this one. I did some more digging and think I must have misread the whole 'photographer' angle - there have been shows dedicated to his films, but not by Anderson himself. I'll put a link in the next comment that has a bit of info. - but at the end of the day I think my efforts were a bust :) Ah well.

Comment: http://books.google.ca/books?id=QlKh3XzdQ-UC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=wes%20anderson%20%2b%20robert%20mapplethorpe&source=bl&ots=fI-f2uoLsU&sig=ry_MbFPlshISoZbSzHY0Q5GkOZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MzezUrSKOYjo2AX4w4GYBw&ved=0CHEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=wes%20anderson%20%2b%20robert%20mapplethorpe&f=false